# Placing User Feedback Popup on Top of Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database

What I am trying to do is allow users to leave feedback on top of an image, similar to what Flickr or Facebook does (where you see the little squares on images, hover over them, and the comment/tag shows up). When other users see the image, they see the little squares created by other users, and when they hover over them, they get a tooltip that displays, not comments, but information pulled from the creator's own profile items (pulled from the database).

I'd like to use some jQuery tooltip as the display of that information, but I am just uncertain on how to go about allowing a user to place that information on top of an image.

Comment: That is not a simple thing to implement. What kind of experience do you have with JS?

Comment: I've had about a year of experience, moreso focused in jQuery. I actually found a plugin that does it, so hopefully I may be able to work with it to tailor it to my needs: http://www.bennadel.com/projects/jquery-photo-tagger.htm

If you could offer any further suggestions, I'd be glad to hear them :)

Comment: I would try to use that one. Ben Nadel makes really good plugins. I'm glad you found something that will work for your needs.